# Why won't it send_keys to the comment box?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I am busy creating an Instagram bot that will automatically comment on posts in my Instagram feed. The problem is when I try to send_keys to the comment box it does not work. I set up the login screen to send the keys and it works perfectly, but why is this step not working?

This is my code:

```
def send_comment(self):


    self.browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
    actionChain = webdriver.ActionChains(self.browser)

    comment = self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('form input')[0]

    comment.send_keys("Great")
    comment.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    print('sent comment')
```

This is the error that comes up: 
    
    `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument:
    File not found : Great`

So I figured it is probably looking for a file path. I created a text document containing the comment I would like to submit enclosed within parentheses (standard Python format). In this format:
    
    `comment.send_keys("C:/Users/bbrown/Desktop/comment_doc.txt")`

However, this gives me a different error now:
    
    `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument:`

and on the web browser with Instagram open it gives a message when trying to run that part of the code. "Upload Failed. Only images can be uploaded.". So I don't believe this is the right format. Where am I going wrong? Any help would be amazing!!

Comment: seems to be you are pointing to the wrong element. Did you checked css in the dev tools.

Comment: What do you mean by "dev tools"? I check the html source code through chrome and it is pointing to a <textarea> tag. However, when trying to put that into the "find_elememts_by_css_selector" it gives me this error: "'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'". So then I tried adding a index of 0 at the end and it gave me the error that list index is out of range.

Comment: Can you try changing the line to `comment = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('form input:nth-of-type(1)')`. Try adding the Expected conditions to make sure the element is loaded on the page.

Comment: Dev Tools, as mentioned by @supputuri is a tool included in FF or Chrome (and others) that helps you to check the code of your HTML, which allows you to execute some javascript commands on the page. It's essential to know it. Please see: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that should be kept in mind when working with Selenium like waiting for some time. Selenium code will executed very fast but when you have to find the web page on the element, it will be dependent on the speed of the internet and your hardware.So to avoid "No Such Element" errors, you should include `sleep()` or `wait` command until some element is visible. I prefer using `time.sleep(time_amount_in_sec)`.
and if you are talking about the comment section, just be sure to click on it before you start sending keys to avoid errors. A very similar bot is described [here](https://www.github.com/deshwalmahesh/Instabot).

A snippet from the code is:

```
def comment(i):
    list1=["niceeee ","aweeesome ","supeeerr ","cooool "]
    list2=[":)", ";)",":o"]

    p=random.randint(0,3)
    q=random.randint(0,2)

    paste=list1[p]+list2[q]

    a=br.find_element_by_class_name('_b6i0l').click()
    time.sleep(1.85)
    b=br.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='_bilrf']")
    b.send_keys(paste)
    b.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)
    with open('commented.txt','a') as f:
        x=str(i)
        f.write('%s\n'%x)

    return()
```

Hope it'll be helpful.

**NOTE**- It is old one so try to change the classes accordingly as they change the website classes very often.